# Request permission in fragment return always false

Tags: java, android, permissions

My goal is to obtain permission to access the gallery and take an image from a fragment.
This is my code

```
    binding.memoryImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
      try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
          openGallery();
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });
  private void openGallery() {
    Intent iGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    iGallery.setType("image/*");
    iGallery.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    folderResult.launch(iGallery);
  }
  private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
      new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
      result -> {
        if (result) {
          openGallery();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
  );
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> folderResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          imageURI = result.getData().getData();
          binding.memoryImage.setImageURI(imageURI);
        }
      }
    });
```

The problem is that result il always false. Whats wrong?

Comment: May be because [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) has no effect since Android 13?

Comment: @Robert it was so easy : ) thk!